# Set of vectors closed under restricted permutation operations

Tags: finite-groups, permutations, permutation-groups

Let $V=\{v_1,\cdots v_k\}$ a set of non zero different norm one vectors in $R^d$, $k>2$. I am trying to demonstrate that if $Q=\{P_i\in R^{k\times k},i=1,\cdots,k\}$ is a set of permutations such that:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum_{q=1}^{k}P_q=J\\
&& P_i\circ P_j =\mathbb{0}, i\neq j\\
&& P_iP_j=P_l\;\;\forall\;i,j\;\;\exists\;l
\end{eqnarray}
($J\in R^{k\times k}$ the all-ones matrix, $\circ$ the Hadamard product) 
and
$$
v^T_iP_q v_j=v_{l,q}\;\;\forall\;i,j\;\;\exists\;l\\
$$
($v_{l,q}$ the $q^{th}$ component of the $v_l$ vector) then the $V$ is a collection of vectors with one only one component different from zero equal to one. Is it true? Counterexamples? Thanks!

Comment: Where do your conditions come from?

Comment: Hi, originally I was wondering if there exists a set of (equivalent) Latin squares that are closed under  matrix multiplication. The conditions on the permutations come from the latin square constraints. The last one from the latin squares matrix  multiplication clousure condition. Cheers.

Comment: So, the third condition says that your permutations form a group, and the second says that they are all fixed-point-free, right?

Comment: That would seem to imply that the basic case is when $k=d,$ in which case your permutation group is generated by a $d$-cycle. I assume that your conjecture is easily checked in that case.

Comment: Yes,  the case I am more interested in $k=d$. Sorry why is it easy to check in the case the permutation is generated by a $d-$cycle? Thanks!

Comment: Because in this case you can assume that $P_i$ = (1 2 3 \dots d)^i,$ and then just check what the last condition (which is the only non-vacuous one) implies.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I think that  if I write  $P_i=(1 2 3 \cdots d)$,  $P_i$  is a cyclic permutation which is not always the case! Fabio